# How do I extend a Ruby class inside a module?

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm trying to extend the `File` class inside a module. Here's my (abbreviated) code:

```rb
module Wireshark

   # Extend the file class to write a header comment
   class File
     def write_header
        self.puts '/* ' + Wireshark::AUTOGEN_LABEL + ' */'
        self.puts '/* ' + Wireshark::timestamp + ' */'
     end
   end

   # Read a file
   def read
     begin
        file = File.read 'file'
     rescue IOError
        STDERR.puts 'Error reading file.'
        return
     end
   end
end
```

When I run my code, I'm getting

```
undefined method `read' for Wireshark::File:Class (NoMethodError)
```

when I try to run `file.read`. I tried getting rid of the module encapsulation, but I'd like to only extend the `File` class inside my module, not in the rest of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

```
module Wireshark
   module File
     def write_header
        self.puts '/* ' + Wireshark::AUTOGEN_LABEL + ' */'
        self.puts '/* ' + Wireshark::timestamp + ' */'
     end
   end

   # Extend File with the methods in the Wireshark::File module
   ::File.send :include, Wireshark::File

   # Read a file
   def read
     begin
        file = ::File.read 'file'
     rescue IOError
        STDERR.puts 'Error reading file.'
        return
     end
   end
end
```

The general idea here is that we define a `Wireshark::File` module that holds the methods you want to include on the `File` class, then you can just include them on File directly.

You'll also notice that in the `read` method, I changed `File` to `::File`. Ruby will walk up the tree to try to find the nearest matching value for a given constant, so since you are in the `Wireshark` module, and there is a constant named `File` in that scope, using just `File` gets you `Wireshark::File`. Specifying `::File` means "The `File` constant at the top-level namespace".

Comment: Could I do something like `include`ing `::File` in the `Wireshark::File` module so I don't have to use `file = ::File` in the `read` method?

Comment: That likely won't work. You could alias ::File to another constant (`RealFile = ::File) then `RealFile.open` or whatever, but that would be unconventional and is not recommended. `::File` is self-descriptive and standard Ruby, so it will be easily maintained by other programmers.

Comment: @burwell: You have two classes, both named `File`, both with similar responsibilities, both used in the same context. That just reeks of incredibly bad design. The fact that you have to jump through hoops to work with that design is not an inconvenience that you need to work around, it's trying to tell you something, namely that you have an extraordinarily convoluted design that needs fixing.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for your reply. I'll just stick with `::File`. @Jörg, I'm not sure that you're understanding the situation. I don't _want_ to have two classes; I'd like to just extend Ruby's `File` class. The practice of "extending" classes to create more specific sub-types is extremely common and nothing revolutionary. I am just new to Ruby, and don't know the "ruby way" to accomplish this.

Comment: @burwell: I think I understand now, you are looking for something like scoped monkeypatching? I think "extremely common and nothing revolutionary" is a gross mischaracterization of that. Scoped monkeypatching is still very much an open research problem, if you have found a way to make that "extremely common", that's a PhD right there. The Smalltalk community is researching *selector namespaces*, the Java community *classboxes*, the Ruby community has toyed with both of those and is now experimenting with *refinements*, but none of those is even close to production-ready.

Comment: @burwell You could consider subclassing File, and adding the functionality you want, as well - that way, your Wireshark-specific functionality would be on your Wireshark::File class rather than in the general File class.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Ruby it's not possible to do this, but it is a popular [proposed extension called "refinements"](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-refinements-an-overview-of-a-new-proposed-ruby-feature-3978.html).

If you need to patch the core `File` class, you'll need to do that as a monkey patch, and this affects all instances of `File` anywhere in your Ruby process.

Normally you can do it this way:

```
# Define the instance methods you want to overide
module MyFileHacksInstanceMethods
  def read
    # ... (reimplementation) ...
  end
end

# Force load these in the File class
class File
  include MyFileHacksInstanceMethods
end
```

What you've declared in your example here is an independent class called `Wireshark::File` because it's within that module's namespace. `::File` is the main class (`::` being a prefix to force absolute name, sort of like `/` for filesystems).

Comment: You could 'fix' your code by using this line: `class ::File`, but as @tadman says, this will patch File everywhere.